# How to prevent auto start of tomcat/jetty in Spring Boot when I only want to use RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to use RestTemplate/TestRestTemplate by including the artifact in a SpringBoot application

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But this automatically starts Tomcat or Jetty.  Is there a way to turn it off, or by not including the above artifact.  TestRestTemplate is in the boot artifact, but not the base RestTemplate.

Comment: By any chance do you have the reference of spring-boot-starter-web? Because that pulls the tomcat automatically as a dependency.

Comment: No I don't use spring-boot-starter-web.  That's why I added spring-web instead.

Comment: What's the type of your application? Is it a Web or Command line or Scheduler based application? Also, can you share the Main Application class and pom file for reference? I have a sample application which is a Command line application and does not pull tomcat as a dependency.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Spring Boot is not going to start a web container if it's not present. `spring-web` does not provide any embedded container. You may want to analyse the dependencies of your project (try `mvn dependency:tree`).

If you want to make sure a web server is not started in your spring boot application, you can set the following configuration key

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Or you can use the `SpringApplicationBuilder`

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApp.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
```

Comment: Thank you. I addapted it to `SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class); app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE); app.run(args).close();` and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 22):

Since Spring Boot 2.0.0 this property is deprecated and following is the new way:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

This change is because Spring Boot the support for [reactive server.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can just close the app according to https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/.  Although this still stars Tomcat, but will stop the app at the end without keeping the tread running.

```
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args).close();
```

Comment: This closes the application context. You shouldn't close it unless you want to stop the whole application or you really know what you are doing.