# Spring boot Start webapplication with delay programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I like spring boot but I can't figure/find out how can I achieve this:
I have executable spring application. I need applicationContext, do some stuff and then start "webPart" (REST api). Is it possible to tell spring "don't start jetty automatically, I'll start it myself", or I need to compose application myself?

I would like to do something like that. Do anyone have any idea?

```java
@SpringApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        try {
            doSth(ctx);
            startWeb();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            clean();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I want to use "web-part" but later and when I decided to (f.e. Exception is not thrown...). I don't want to prevent web-context to be used at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent auto start of tomcat/jetty in Spring Boot when I only want to use RestTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897165/how-to-prevent-auto-start-of-tomcat-jetty-in-spring-boot-when-i-only-want-to-use)

Comment: I think my problem is different. I dont want to not use web-context I want to let it wait till I say its time to start web-part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to destroy the first context (which has web disabled) and then start a new context with web enabled.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).run(args);

try {
    doSomething(ctx);
} catch (Exception e){
    //abort
} finally {
    ctx.close();
}

//New context has web enabled.
ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
doSomething(ctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent jetty/tomcat start automatically like they did here [How to prevent auto start of tomcat/jetty in Spring Boot when I only want to use RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897165/how-to-prevent-auto-start-of-tomcat-jetty-in-spring-boot-when-i-only-want-to-use)